# Access Violation At Address In Module 'pdfcie.dll'

Tags: asp.net

Hello i have this question when im trying to display a file in a webform the error in the tittle appear im trying to open 2 pdf files from my disk in 2 different popup. Always the first work good but the second always show this error. What is happen? somebody could help me pls?

Answer (score 0):

This problem went away when I rebooted